# Copy screenlog.n file and restart log?

Tags: linux, logging, gnu, gnu-screen

I'm running a application using gnu screen and logging everything the the -L flag.  The screenlog.n file is being created just fine.  What I would like to copy the contents of that file to something like `log_<date>`, and then clear the screenlog.n file to start logging the next day.  So far I have only found solutions for appending, or leaving the screenlog.n file to keep all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that screen will create a new screenlog.n file automatically if I delete the existing one while a screen session is detached. I simply scheduled a cronjob to copy and rename the existing file and then delete it.  A new screenlog.n file is created as soon as there is something new to log.